# Why is Git showing that I changed local files when I have not?

Tags: git

I occasionally face a problem in git when I work with team.
Some times it appears to me I changed files in the `Local Repository` but I have not. 
Today I faced this problem again, it shows that I changed a lot of files but I have not.
When I run `git diff -w` it shows the difference.
I also tried with Vcode and it shows the same difference.
[image]

Has anyone faced a problem like this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that files are not being modified if git tells you it has. I have never had an issue like that.

A couple of things I can think of that might create modification without you realizing:

1. The IDE you use may create project files that you didn't realize; although by the look of it, it doesn't seem to be the case for you.
2. Are there anything in your code that might generate some files for you? When you run it or even change something, there might be modifications or creations based on that. I don't know much about php, but eg. xsd files may be set up to create java stuff for you.
3. Did you apply git stash apply by any chance? If you have git stash something before and applied it, your previous changes might be added.
4. Anything outside of the project that is making those changes in your local repo.

I'll add if I can think of anything more but it's unlikely that it's git.

Comment: this change made by another one in the team but it shows that I did it(and need to commit it ), I think this situation more complicated

Comment: Try deleting your local repo and cloning your project again. And then see if the issue persists in your branch. Make sure you have all changes you need in remote before doing it.

Comment: I can't do this Scenario because there is more than 30 developer work on it and most of them faced this problem also. I think this problem cased because someone do something wrong

Comment: Is it always the same files that get modified?

Comment: No, but there is a pattern that makes sense to me this problem show when someone deleted his modification and push them.
 then after few days one or two from the team face this problem